# How to open the Firefox History window with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: firefox, shortcut-keys

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18 and am running Firefox 45. I often use the History window to view which sites I have previously been to however it is slightly long getting there so I am wondering if there is a keyboard shortcut to open the window?

Comment: "slightly long getting there" ... what does that mean? O.o

Comment: @muru: Well, I have to press the menu, and then the History button, and then the other History button... And my browser is rather slow anyway and the menu doesn't always come up so it all takes a while...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to open the history window (actually it's called "Library" window, but contains the history).

To open the history sidebar, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> is enough.

You can actually easily find the shortcut out by looking at the "History" menu of Firefox:

[image: history menu]

Comment: Where is this "History menu" you speak of?

Comment: In the menu bar of your Firefox window, there are `File Edit View History Bookmarks Tools Help`. On Unity, the menu bar is usually integrated into the desktop panel or the window's title bar and only appears when you hover the mouse cursor over it.

Answer (score 5):

Just use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.

Here you find a overview about Firefox shortcuts which is taken from this [source](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly):

```
1.  Navigation

    Back                                Alt+←
                                        Ctrl+[

    Forward                             Alt+→
                                        Ctrl+]


    Home                                Alt+Home

    Open File                           Ctrl+O

    Reload                              F5
                                        Ctrl+R

    Reload (override cache)             Ctrl+F5
                                        Ctrl+Shift+R

    Stop                                Esc


2. Current Page

    Go Down a Screen                    Page Down

    Go Up a Screen                      Page Up

    Go to Bottom of Page                End

    Go to Top of Page                   Home

    Move to Next Frame                  F6

    Move to Previous Frame              Shift+F6

    Print                               Ctrl+ P

    Save Page As                        Ctrl+S

    Zoom In                             Ctrl++

    Zoom Out                            Ctrl+-

    Zoom Reset                          Ctrl+0


3. Editing

    Copy                                Ctrl+C

    Cut                                 Ctrl+X

    Delete                              Del

    Paste                               Ctrl+V

    Paste (as plain text)               Ctrl+Shift+V

    Redo                                Ctrl+Shift+Z

    Select All                          Ctrl+A

    Undo                                Ctrl+Z


4. Search

    Find                                Ctrl+F

    Find Again                          F3
                                        Ctrl+G

    Find Previous                       Shift+F3
                                        Ctrl+Shift+G

    Quick Find within link-text only    '

    Quick Find                          /

    Close the Find or Quick Find bar    Esc          (when the Find or Quick Find bar is focused)
    Focus Search bar                    Ctrl+K
                                        Ctrl+J

    Quickly switch between              Ctrl+↑
    search engines                      Ctrl+↓    (when Search Bar is focused)

    View menu to switch, add or manage  Alt+↑
    search engines                      Alt+↓     (when Search Bar is focused)
                                        F4


5. Windows & Tabs

    Close Tab                           Ctrl+W
                                        Ctrl+F4       (except for App Tabs)

    Close Window                        Ctrl+Shift+W
                                        Alt+F4

    Move Tab in focus Left              Ctrl+Shift+Page Up

    Move Tab in focus Right             Ctrl+Shift+Page Down

    Move Tab in focus to start          Ctrl+Home

    Move Tab in focus to end            Ctrl+End

    Mute/Unmute Audio                   Ctrl+M

    New Tab                             Ctrl+T

    New Window                          Ctrl+N

    New Private Window                  Ctrl+Shift+P

    Next Tab                            Ctrl+Tab
                                        Ctrl+Page Down

    Open Address in New Tab             Alt+Enter         (from Location Bar or Search Bar)

    Previous Tab                        Ctrl+Shift+Tab
                                        Ctrl+Page Up

    Undo Close Tab                      Ctrl+Shift+T

    Undo Close Window                   Ctrl+Shift+N

    Select Tab 1 to 8                   Alt+1 to 8

    Select Last Tab                     Alt+9

    Tab Groups View                     Ctrl+Shift+E

    Close Tab Groups View               Esc

    Next Tab Group                      Ctrl+`        (only for some keyboard layouts)

    Previous Tab Group                  Ctrl+Shift+`   (only for some keyboard layouts)


6. History

    History sidebar                     Ctrl+H

    Library window (History)            Ctrl+Shift+H

    Clear Recent History                Ctrl+Shift+Del


7. Bookmarks

    Bookmark This Page                  Ctrl+D

    Bookmarks sidebar                   Ctrl+B

    Library window (Bookmarks)          Ctrl+Shift+O


8. Tools

    Downloads                           Ctrl+Shift+Y

    Add-ons                             Ctrl+Shift+A

    Toggle Developer Tools              F12
                                        Ctrl+Shift+I

    Web Console                         Ctrl+Shift+K

    Inspector                           Ctrl+Shift+C

    Debugger                            Ctrl+Shift+S

    Style Editor                        Shift+F7

    Profiler                            Shift+F5

    Network                             Ctrl+Shift+Q

    Developer Toolbar                   Shift+F2

    Responsive Design View              Ctrl+Shift+M

    Scratchpad                          Shift+F4

    Page Source                         Ctrl+U

    Browser Console                     Ctrl+Shift+J

    Page Info                           Ctrl+I


9. PDF Viewer

    Next page                           N or J or →

    Previous page                       P or K or ←

    Zoom in                             Ctrl++

    Zoom out                            Ctrl+-

    Automatic Zoom                      Ctrl+0

    Rotate the document clockwise       R

    Rotate counterclockwise             Shift+R

    Switch to Presentation Mode         Ctrl+Alt+P

    Toggle Hand Tool                    H

    Focus the Page Number input box     Ctrl+Alt+G


10. Miscellaneous

    Complete .com Address               Ctrl+Enter

    Complete .net Address               Shift+Enter

    Complete .org Address               Ctrl+Shift+Enter

    Delete Selected Autocomplete Entry  Del

    Toggle Full Screen                  F11

    Toggle Menu Bar activation (show-   Alt (KDE) 
    ing it temporarily when hidden)     F10 (GNOME)

    Show/Hide Add-on Bar                Ctrl+/

    Caret Browsing                      F7

                                        F6
    Select Location Bar                 Alt+D
                                        Ctrl+L


Media shortcuts

    Toggle Play / Pause                 Space bar

    Decrease volume                     ↓

    Increase volume                     ↑

    Mute audio                          Ctrl+↓

    Unmute audio                        Ctrl+↑

    Seek back 15 seconds                ←

    Seek back 10 %                      Ctrl+←

    Seek forward 15 seconds             →

    Seek forward 10 %                   Ctrl+→

    Seek to the beginning               Home

    Seek to the end                     End
```

Answer (score 2):

Within Firefox, from the Hamburger Menu, you can get to the help:

[image]      
[image]

And that leads to [Firefox's help page on Keyboard Shortcuts](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly):

> History sidebar   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>
>   Library window (History)  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> +
>   <kbd>H</kbd>
>   Clear Recent History  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> +
>   <kbd>Del</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

the easiest ways to do this are:

type ^ + space + text => it will only search your history
(it is a bit tricky on a mac using non-eng keyboard settings, as you have to press space twice to make the ^ symbol)

type * + space + text => it will only search your bookmarks

type % + space + text => it will only search your tabs